# How to validate specific email address using ng-pattern?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

I have email validation that has specific format `ab123c@email.com` or `ab1234@email.com` its validationg first 5 characters but not the complete email address using angularjs `ng-pattern`. How can i validate specific email address using angularjs ?

**main.html**

```
<div layout="row">
    <md-input-container flex="100">
        <label>Cc</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="notifyCtrl.cc" ng-list="," ng-pattern="pattern(user.type)">
        <div class="help-block" ng-messages="notifyForm.email.$error" ng-show="notifyForm.email.$touched && notifyForm.email.$invalid">
            <div ng-if="user.type === 'notify'">
                <div ng-message="pattern">
                    An email name must only contain a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or _ characters.(ie. ab123c@tad.com, ab1234@tad.com
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

**ctrl.js**

```
var emailFormat = new RegExp('^[a-z]{2}[0-9]{3}[a-z0-9]$'); 

$scope.pattern = function(type){ 
    if(type === 'notify') {
        return emailFormat; 
    }  
};
```

Comment: What's `user.type`, why are you using this custom `pattern` function in your controller?

Comment: @chsdk i have one modal window that is being used for multiple events on user page, so in my case `user.type = 'notify'`.where i should implement this `pattern` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your Input email you can use the following ng-pattern

```
ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best pattern to check valid email address:

```
ng-pattern='/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/'
```

### You can try this another regex:

```
ng-pattern='/^(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22))(?:\\.(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-+[a-z0-9]+)*\\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-+[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\\]))$/';
```